# How to inject dependencies in spring for objects created dynamically at run time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

```
public class PlatformEventFactory {

    public PlatformEvent createEvent(String eventType) {
        if (eventType.equals("deployment_activity")) {
            return new UdeployEvent();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

I have a factory class which creates `PlatformEvent` type objects based on the eventType.

UdeployEvent class has dependency on `private RedisTemplate<String, Object> template` on which I want to inject after the `UdeployEvent` object has been created.

```
@Component
public class UdeployEvent implements PlatformEvent {

    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> template;
    private UDeployMessage uDeployMessage;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UdeployEvent.class);

    public UdeployEvent() {
        uDeployMessage = new UDeployMessage();
    }


    /*public void sendNotification() {

    }*/

    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setTemplate(RedisTemplate<String, Object> template) {
        this.template = template;
        System.out.println("Injection done");
    }
}
```

When the new object is returned for `UdeployEvent` I get null pointer exception for template. I believe the reason for that is because it is not referring to the same bean which is created when spring boots up. **How can I inject dependencides for newly created objects at run time.**

Comment: Your set method causes [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) and makes your component mutable, which are code smells. The type of factory you define is [a code smell as well](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100). Your code will be simpler without. The `LoggerFactory` is an [Ambient Context](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ploeh/2007/07/23/ambient-context/) which is an anti-pattern; you should inject a `Logger` directly into the `UdeployEvent` using **Constructor Injection**.

Comment: If `RedisTemplate<String, Object>` is some kind of runtime data, [this advice](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99) applies. Either you inject some sort of `IContext` into the constructor that allows you to retrieve it, or you inject the runtime data into the `sendNotification` method.

Comment: @Steven will just adding the template as a constructor injection and checking for null remove temporal coupling or something else also needs to be done.

Comment: @Steven RedisTemplate is a configuration class

Answer (score 6):

You should not create components manually. Let Spring to do this. Use `ApplicationContext` to get instance of component. All fields will be automatically injected:

```
@Component
public class PlatformEventFactory {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    public PlatformEvent createEvent(String eventType) {
        if (eventType.equals("deployment_activity")) {                
            return context.getBean(UdeployEvent.class);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

To make Spring create new instance of `UdeployEvent` component every time you request it, specify scope of component as `SCOPE_PROTOTYPE`:

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class UdeployEvent implements PlatformEvent {

    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> template;

    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setTemplate(RedisTemplate<String, Object> template) {
        this.template = template;
        System.out.println("Injection done");
    }

    ...
}
```

Now every time you call `context.getBean(UdeployEvent.class)` Spring will create new instance of component with fully initialized dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating objects by hand, dependency injection is not performed in created object, and the field is null.

The easy way would be to use `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` `autowireBean()`
Example:

```
@Component
public class PlatformEventFactory {

    @Autowired  
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    public PlatformEvent createEvent(String eventType) {
        if (eventType.equals("deployment_activity")) {
            PlatformEvent platformEvent = new UdeployEvent();
            beanFactory.autowireBean(platformEvent);
            return platformEvent;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

`beanFactory.autowireBean(platformEvent)` should inject your fields and it should work fine.

There are more extended solutions with @Configuration, but they produce a lot of boilerplate code and doesn't give to much in return.

Haven't seen cleaner solution in Spring (like @AssistedInject in Guice).

Source:
http://www.kubrynski.com/2013/09/injecting-spring-dependencies-into-non.html

Comment: About `AutowireCapableBeanFactory` official Spring's javadoc says that:  *"This subinterface of BeanFactory is not meant to be used in normal application code..."*. Another point, that Spring documentation advices to generally use `ApplicationContext` instead of `FactoryBean`.  Take a look: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate your bean as `SCOPE_PROTOTYPE`, as @ken-bekov pointed out.

To obtain an instance of prototype bean you can use injected (autowired) `org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider<T>`, rather than `ApplicationContext`. Type parameter of this provider should be `UdeployEvent`.
Additionally you can provide arguments for class constructor or factory method in `get` method. One downside of this approach is that call to `get` won't be statically checked.

One more way to solve your issue is trying to use [Google's AutoFactory](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory).